# Angular ts - importing components with local data from ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

I'm relativly new to Angular2 and i'm currently struggling with importing components in ngFor loop.

It appears that when you import components with data in ngFor loops, it checks for values in the .ts file and not the local variable used in ngFor. What I  want to do is to send the variable used in ngFor to the next component.

**accommodations.component (parent view)**

ts:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { AccommodationModel } from '../../../../models/reservations/accommodation-model';

@Component({
    selector: 'reservations-reservation-accommodations',
    templateUrl: './accommodations.component.html'
})

export class AccommodationsComponent {
    constructor() { }

    @Input() accommodations: AccommodationModel[];
}
```

html:

```
<div class="card-block">
                <ngb-tabset>
                    <ngb-tab *ngFor="let accommodation of accommodations" title="{{accommodation.arrivalDate}}">
                        <ng-template ngbTabContent>
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped content-divider-up">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>ArrivalDate</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                {{accommodation.arrivalDate}}
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </ng-template>
                    </ngb-tab>
                </ngb-tabset>

                <reservations-reservation-accommodations-costs [costs]="accommodation.costs"></reservations-reservation-accommodations-costs>
            </div>
```

**costs.component (child view)**

ts:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { CostModel } from '../../../../../models/reservations/cost-model';

@Component({
    selector: 'reservations-reservation-accommodations-costs',
    templateUrl: './costs.component.html'
})

export class CostsComponent {
    constructor() { }

    @Input() costs: CostModel[];
}
```

html:

```
<div class="row content-divider-up">
    <div class="col">
        {{costs.length}}
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I send **let accommodation(.costs)** in ngFor to **costs.component**? With the code above, costs is always undefined in costs.component because its looks for a variable named "accommodation" in the accommodations.components.ts file which i don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<reservations-reservation-accommodations-costs [costs]="accommodation.costs"></reservations-reservation-accommodations-costs>
```

**accommodation** is a local template reference for the for loop and you are using the reference outside the scope of the for loop you need to put this inside the for loop in order for accommodation to be defined

Comment: Wow really? Did i miss that? How embarrassing haha, thanks. Edit: Hmm I wonder what happens when the local variable and the one outside the scrope has the same name.